# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Chemistry's [1st moderator election](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: ManishEarth] [image: jonsca] [image: Martin - ãƒžãƒ¼ãƒãƒ³]

They've replaced [the pro tempore crew](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) — please thank both teams for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with the new crew as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4612156788047872/0).

Comment: Epic news! all hail our overlords!

Answer (score 14):

I saw myself responsible for thanking our pro tem dudes! They've done a great job! We still have a long way to go, but a large portion of what chem.SE's today is because of the monumental discipline of our previous moderators. $\mathbf{Our~ hats~ are~ off~ to~ you,~ \color{red}{@F'x}, \color{blue}{@Jonsca}~ and \color{green}{~@Manish}!}$

---

### Kudos to our new mods!

[image] [image]
I'm more than happy to see three of our most devoted members as our new [over](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22343231#22343231)[lords](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/2015-community-moderator-election-results#comment1887_2828). The intention of this post is to congratulate them. They do deserve their place as the [highest privileged community members](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/). [**Congrats @Manish, @Martin and @Jonsca!**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22343127#22343127)

**Martin**: First to get "[Marshal](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/marshal)", this guy is the Liberty statue of caring moderation in chem.SE. He has edited 1396 posts till now, which is approximately 7% percent of all of the posts. Now, some posts are too bad for an edit, and there are numerous others which were formatted very neatly by neat authors<sup>1</sup> and didn't need an edit. So a little maths and calculation tells me we owe <strike>me</strike> Martin a great deal of chem.SE's cleanness and polish.
The guy [likes his data clean and arranged](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2807/2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire/2814#2814), ya know.

**Jonsca** & **Manish**: As a member of the pro tempore mods, these guys

- Lead by example.
- Were a masterpiece of positive and contributing behavior.
- Showed respect, even for the most troublesome of users and *he who must not be named*.
- actively participated and responded to flags ASAP.

I (and a bunch of people here) saw no reason they shouldn't continue being awesome at being awesome at what they were doing, so I'm very very happy we officially have 'em as our fellow mods again.

---

<sub>1: Like me.

<sub><sub>Yeah$\ldots$ so this is definitely **not** an answer to any question. If you feel depressed of not having downvoted something recently, *this* is your chance!</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: Thank you.  You have proven yourself a great user time and again, so see what the future holds :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I shall be your humble servant ;)

Comment: Thanks! :) Here's to the continued awesomeness of Chem.SE!

Answer (score 6):

To expand on my comment - congratulations to our new Overlords ....erm... I mean Moderators.

We had to coax (i.e. nag - mostly from M.A.Ramezani) Martin to even nominate, but he, alongside jonsca and Manish make a great team to see us, as a community of chemistry boffins, go forward.

They will build on a the strong community lead by the excellent work from the pro-tem moderators.